# Show options based on selected value

Tags: php, mysql

```
<select id="prodi" name="product_names" style="padding:6px;">                                                                        
  <?php
    $resultsTicket = $mysqli->query("SELECT
                                     product_list.product_name, 
                                     product_package.size 
                                     FROM product_list
                                     LEFT JOIN  product_package
                                     ON product_list.product_code = package.product_code     
                                     ORDER BY   product_list.id ASC");
    $orders = array();     
    if ($resultsTicket) {
        while($obj = $resultsTicket->fetch_object()) {
            $orders[$obj->size][$obj->product_name]  = array(
                'product_name' => $obj->product_name, 
                'size' => $obj->size, 
                'status' => $obj->status);
        }
        foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
            foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
    echo '<option value="'.$obj->product_name.'">' . $data['product_name'] . '</option>';
            }
        }
    echo '</select></div>';
    echo '<div style="display:block; padding:6px; border: solid thin white;">
          <span style="width:60px; display:inline-block; padding:6px;">Package</span>
          <select name="packageInfi" style="padding:6px;">';
    }
    echo '<option value="">'.$order_id.'</option>';
    echo '</select></div>';
    ?>
```

What I am going to do with my code above is to get the size/package based on the product name which has been selected

Here is the place where I will choose the product name: `echo '<option value="'.$obj->product_name.'">' . $data['product_name'] . '</option>';`

And here is the place where the package should showing up based on the product has been selected above: `echo '<option value="">'.$order_id.'</option>';`

But instead of showing up the package based on the product which has been selected, it only shows me the last package of the products.

Here is the sketch of the products:

```
      ------------------------------------------- 
      no       product_name     product_code              
      -------------------------------------------
      1        product_one      001 
      2        product_one      002 
      3        product_one      003 
      4        product_one      004 


      ------------------------------------------------- 
      product_code         package     price              
      -------------------------------------------------
       001                  2kg        10
       001                  3kg        20 
       001                  4kg        30  
       001                  5kg        40 

       002                  6kg        50 
       002                  7kg        60  
       002                  8kg        70 
       002                  9kg        80
```

From the first table, I only want to get the data of the all products name, while from the second table I want to get the size and the price of each products.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option value="'.$obj->product_name.'">' . $data['product_name'] . '</option>';
```

`$obj->product_name` is out of the loop. so this is the reason your getting only the last. I believe this should be also `$data['product_name']`

Comment: I have changed it to data[product_name], but it still doens't change the result.

Comment: did you try to `var_dump` or `print_r` the `$orders`? whats the result?